# Change UI When Multiple Retrofit Calls Return in Android

Tags: android, service, retrofit

I start a service, in Activity, in which I make three Retrofit calls to post data. Everything works fine. But I want two things

1. To show/hide ProgressBar from service when all three calls return
2. Getting to know that all three of the Retrofit calls have returned (either successfully or failed)

For the first part, I have used LocalBroadcastManager. But for the second part, I don't know what to use. How would I know that all three of the Retrofit calls have returned? Here is the logic of what I have done so far.

```
void onHandleIntent(){

AppDB appDB = AppDB.getDatabase(MyService.this);
    Dao policeDutyDao = appDB.getDao1();

    ArrayList<POJO1> pojo1Notes =
            (ArrayList<POJO1>)policeDutyDao.getPojo1NotesBySyncStatus("0");
    ArrayList<POJO1> pojo2Notes =
            (ArrayList<POJO2>)policeDutyDao.getPojo2NotesBySyncStatus("0");

    GeneralDataObject generalDataObject = new GeneralDataObject();
    generalDataObject.setPojo1Notes(pojo1Notes);
    generalDataObject.setPojo2Notes(pojo2Notes);

    sendDataToServer(generalDataObject);
}

void sendDataToServer(GeneralDataObject obj){
    sendPojo1Notes(obj.getPojo1Notes());
    sendPojo2Notes(obj.getPojo2Notes());
}

void sendPojo1Notes(){
       RetrofitDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitDataService.class);
       Call<Object> call = service.postPojoOneNote(inputParams);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, final Response<Object> response) {
               if(response != null) {
                   if (response.body() != null) {
                       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                           Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onResponse: PostReview() ===== SUCCESS");
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onResponse: PostReview()" + t.toString());
           }
       });
}

void sendPojo2Notes(){
       RetrofitDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitDataService.class);
       Call<Object> call = service.postPojoTwoNote(inputParams);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, final Response<Object> response) {
               if(response != null) {
                   if (response.body() != null) {
                       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                           Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onResponse: PostReview() ===== SUCCESS");
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.d(Constants.TAG, "onResponse: PostReview()" + t.toString());
           }
       });
}
```

A lot of detailed code is omitted so that the shared logic makes sense at higher level. Thanks for any input :)

Comment: show what u did so far

Comment: @P.Juni ... I am facing problem in second part. I have done nothing (because I know nothing) except making three Retrofit calls. Do you want me to show that code ?

Comment: Yes Please, do u use coroutines ?

Comment: @P.Juni .... Code shared. And no. I am using Java.